# How can I set visible true for update Panel if Radio Button Checked?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 2 Radio Buttons, both of them should visible an update panel in the page but with different values for the tools in the panel.
P.S: I'm using a page depended on a master page on my website.
When I check any of radio buttons the panel doesn't visible!

```
protected void  Sale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Sale.Checked)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
        PriceLabel.Text = " Sale Price:";
    }
}
    protected void  Rent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Rent.Checked)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Visible=true;
        PriceLabel.Text = " Rent Price:";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code to make UpdatePanel1 invisible ? Also, Is the PriceLabel text getting changed?

Comment: Actually I made UpdatePanal1 invisible in design

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" Visible="false">

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the GUI thread is busy. Try forcing the screen update by calling `Application.DoEvents()`, for example:

```
protected void  Sale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Sale.Checked)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
        PriceLabel.Text = " Sale Price:";
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
    protected void  Rent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Rent.Checked)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Visible=true;
        PriceLabel.Text = " Rent Price:";
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

`DoEvents()` will force all the message in the message queue to be processed.

Comment: Should I use any namespace to use it? because DoEvents does not appear when I press .!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add values to your Radio Buttons like: "1" or "2" then you double click your RadioButton or RadioButtonList and this should appear in the .cs file:

```
    protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == 1)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
        PriceLabel.Text = "Text1:";
    }
    else
    {
        UpdatePanel2.Visible = true;
        PriceLabel.Text = "Text2:";
    }
}
```

So if one of then are selected, it will show the box with the Price Text in it.
This can a better way to do what you want.

Comment: It's not working, the same problem the event doesn't apply when I choose the radio button!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
               UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
               PriceLabel.Text = " Sale Price:";

            }
            else
            {
               UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
               PriceLabel.Text = " Rent Price:";
            }
        }
```